# React leaflet polygon has border stroke when clicking on it (in Chrome)

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a new problem with react leaflet
this problem appeared suddenly.
I don't know what happened and this stroke suddenly appeared around of polygon just in chrome browser when clicking on polygon.
anybody knows what's that and how to remove it?
[image: this is my polygon and after click I got that stroke]

it's too annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I added blow style to my global css code and worked.
when clicking on polygon leaflet add :focus css style to polygon and set outline on that.
this style worked but really I don't like it.
if anyone has an idea, please let me know

```
* {
  outline: none !important;
}
```